# Android options menu opening with delay

Tags: android

I create an options menu with `androidx.widget.toolbar` and working great but why does the popup menu open with a delay for more seconds or milliseconds

```
package com.test.test_option_menu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:title="Quran"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        app:titleTextColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

appbar_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
        android:title="Bagikan Aplikasi"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
        android:title="Info Aplikasi"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
        android:title="Ke Pengaturan"
        app:showAsAction="never">
    </item>
</menu>
```

why the first opening is so delayed?
can I set timing for opening it? I want open it with faster

thanks for the help

Comment: Probably that could happen if you tested that on an emulator... Did you test that on a real device?

Comment: yes I'm running the test on real device